# JsonSerializer<Date>() is not working for java.util.Date field when there is JsonSerializer<Timestamp>()

Tags: java, json, date, timestamp, gson

In my java application I have used both JsonSerializer and JsonSerializer() for serializing java.util.Date and java.sql.Timestamp field respectively.But the problem is, when i parse the object to json string using gson the java.util.Date field uses JsonSerializer() serializer instead of JsonSerializer.
Below is my code.

```
Gson gson;
GsonBuilder builder;
SimpleDateFormat dtf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat dtfDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
builder = new GsonBuilder();

builder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new JsonSerializer<Timestamp>() {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Timestamp src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        dtf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String jsDate = dtf.format(src);
        System.out.println("Timestamp : src - "+src+" jsDate - "+jsDate+" typeOfSrc - "+typeOfSrc);
        return new JsonPrimitive(jsDate);
    }
});
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        String jsDate = dtfDate.format(src);
        System.out.println("Date : src - "+src+" jsDate - "+jsDate+" typeOfSrc - "+typeOfSrc);
        return new JsonPrimitive(jsDate);
    }
});
gson = builder.create();
PersonSubstitution  personSubstitution = loopDao.getPersonSubstitution(Integer.parseInt(deptId),date);
String jsonAccts = gson.toJson(personSubstitution, PersonSubstitution.class);
```

PersonSubstitution.class :

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;


@Entity
@Table(name = "person_substitution")
public class PersonSubstitution implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Departments deptId;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;

    @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Person staffId;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Timestamp createdOn;

    public PersonSubstitution() {

    }

    public PersonSubstitution(int id, Departments deptId, Date date, Person staffId, Timestamp createdOn) {
        this.id = id;
        this.deptId = deptId;
        this.date = date;
        this.staffId = staffId;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Departments getDeptId() {
        return deptId;
    }

    public void setDeptId(Departments deptId) {
        this.deptId = deptId;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Person getStaffId() {
        return staffId;
    }

    public void setStaffId(Person staffId) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Timestamp createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }
}
```

I put `System.out.println()` in both serializer and only Timestamp stement worked as below :

```
Timestamp : src - 2019-11-28 00:00:00.0 jsDate - 2019-11-27 18:30:00 typeOfSrc - class java.sql.Timestamp
Timestamp : src - 2019-11-25 12:08:14.0 jsDate - 2019-11-25 06:38:14 typeOfSrc - class java.sql.Timestamp
```

So is there any way for the Date field to use `builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {...}` instead of `builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Timestamp>() {...}` ??

Comment: Which version of `Gson` do you use? Could you create a simple test which recreates the error? Could you show a `JSON` which is generated?

Comment: @MichałZiober com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1

Comment: I've tried it with version `2.8.5` and everything works properly. Could you upgrade your version?

Comment: @MichałZiober Did u tried with serializer for both Date and Timestamp?

Comment: Yes, both properties are serialised with related serialiser.

Comment: @MichałZiober Ok let me try it with 2.8.5.

Comment: @MichałZiober Same issue with 2.8.5.Which database you use?MySql??

Comment: @MichałZiober Resulted json {"id":78,"date":"2019-11-27 18:30:00","createdOn":"2019-11-25 06:38:14""}

Comment: @MichałZiober I put a sout statement in both serializer and only the timestamp statement worked. src - 2019-11-28 00:00:00.0 jsDate - 2019-11-27 18:30:00 typeOfSrc - class java.sql.Timestamp
src - 2019-11-25 12:08:14.0 jsDate - 2019-11-25 06:38:14 typeOfSrc - class java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: @MichałZiober U used java.util.Date , right??

Comment: Oh, I understand now an issue. I do not use any `DB`, I just created an example where I created manually a `Date` and `Timestamp` objects. But you invoke `SQL` and it returns all `Timestamp`s. `Timestamp` extends `Date` and even you declared type to `Date` in runtime is a `Timestamp` and `Gson` recognise it is a `Timestamp` and uses according to it serialiser.

Comment: @MichałZiober Is there any solution for that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this because in runtime `date` and `createdOn` are `Timestamp`. You need to assign given serialiser to a field. So, you need to create a custom serialiser:

```
class DateJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date> {

    private final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        String formatted = formatter.get().format(src);

        return new JsonPrimitive(formatted);
    }
}
```

`Timestamp` serialiser:

```
class TimestampJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Timestamp> {

    private final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        return dateFormat;
    });

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Timestamp src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        String formatted = formatter.get().format(src);
        return new JsonPrimitive(formatted);
    }
}
```

And declare it for a `Date` field:

```
@JsonAdapter(DateJsonSerializer.class)
private Date date;
```

You can still register it as a global serialiser for a `Date` class:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new TimestampJsonSerializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateJsonSerializer())
        .create();
```

**Note**: I used `ThreadLocal` because `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe.

Comment: Oh , finally it worked.U saved my day.Can u pls include the Timestamp serializer also ??

Comment: Thanku. What is setPrettyPrinting() means?

Comment: @KJEjava48, it formats `JSON` output. Do not use it on production just for testing purposes. Makes it easy to read a `JSON` without extra tools

Comment: What u meaned??then what should i use on production??

Comment: Can u pls suggest what should i try on production environment??

Comment: @ Michał Ziober   U meaned setPrettyPrinting()?? Sorry i thought its about the solution.

Comment: @KJEjava48, `PrettyPrinting` adds tabs and spaces. So, on production env it should not be enabled just to not increase payload size and does not create extra work for `Gson`.

Comment: So its always need to add @JsonAdapter(DateJsonSerializer.class) even if i use global serialiser for Date class. Right??

Comment: @KJEjava48, no. Read my answer: "It works like this because in runtime `date` and `createdOn` are `Timestamp` objects." Notice that you do not have to do that for `createdOn` field. It works like this because even so you declared type for the field `Date` you can assign any object which extends `Date`. Date returned from database actually is a `Timestamp` so `Gson` picked `TimestampJsonSerializer`.

Comment: but its not working without  adding @JsonAdapter(DateJsonSerializer.class)  with date field

Comment: new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new TimestampJsonSerializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateJsonSerializer())
        .create(); is not working for date.Works only if i add @JsonAdapter(DateJsonSerializer.class) with date field

Comment: Everything was fine till now, but now the issue regenerates, i don't know what happend suddenly

Comment: @KJEjava48, create a new question with [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can reproduce it and help with fixing.

Comment: I have added JsonSerializer as per ur answer and it was working pefectly till 1 week before and suddenly i noticed that the issue came back...I havn't changed anything in JsonSerializer...don't know where exactly the issue now...

Comment: @KJEjava48, Generally nothing changes without reason. Check list of commits. Maybe you upgraded `Jackson` verison?

Comment: i don't remember whether i updated jackson, does it affect??

Comment: Do i need to use this JsonSerializer in android client side also??